# Django: How to use apps installed with pip

Tags: python, django, pip

I want to make use of Django's modularity and integrate some external apps that I installed using pip. However, I am encountering difficulties in understanding how can I integrate and use or extend their urls, views, models. There isn't much on this subject, I can't figure why.

Let's take the example of [changuito-cart](https://github.com/angvp/django-changuito):

1. Do i create a folder named "changuito" in root and create urls/views in here, or should I just create a new app named like it?
2. In settings.py I added "changuito" to my installed apps list and I got "no module named 'changuito'" error. How do I add it correctly?
3. What are the basic steps required to integrate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pip installing the app and adding it to your INSTALLED_APPS you should be good to go. There are cases where the name you need to add to your INSTALLED_APPS is different from the package name. Such cases should be apparent from the documentation, otherwise you need to look at the module structure itself. In your case the package is called "django-changuito" and you have to include "changuito" in your INSTALLED_APPS. Be also aware that this particular package depends on MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES settings. Please read the documentation!

Make also sure that the correct virtual environment is activated while installing if you use one.

In general you would not modify the external app itself. This would be quite dangerous since it will start to differ from the upstream and break down the road. If you want to subclass or extend classes of the external app you need to import these classes into your own app before extending or monkey patching. In this case you will create a different class in a different, your app.

Finally, some apps allow for extending templates. Django will search for templates and statics in your project structure first. If you recreate the folder structure of an external app and put new templates in the exact right place. Django will use those.

Comment: On this particular example - changuito: I added it to INSTALLED_APPS and MIDDLEWARE, but it did not find my changuito.urls module, although it exists inside the changuito folder. I used it like this: url(r'^cart', include('changuito.urls')),

Comment: It seems that I needed to add an __init__.py file in the app folder

Comment: Yes, you need to add an init.py to any folder that should be recognized as  a module.